# JTAppleCalendar delegates not working for Swift

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, jtapplecalendar

I have a calendar on my app using `JTAppleCalendar 7.0`.

However the delegates for the same are not working. Please refer to the screenshot of my requirement.

[image]

Somebody kindly share with me the sample delegate functions.

Below is the screenshot of the outlets to the calendar.

[Outlets to the calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HTWY.png)

Below is the entire code for the Calendar.

```
import UIKit
import JTAppleCalendar

class CalendarViewController: UIViewController, JTAppleCalendarViewDelegate, JTAppleCalendarViewDataSource  {



    @IBOutlet weak var calendarView: JTAppleCalendarView!
    let formatter = DateFormatter()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func configureCalendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView) -> ConfigurationParameters {

        formatter.dateFormat  = "yyyy MM dd"
        formatter.timeZone = Calendar.current.timeZone
        formatter.locale = Calendar.current.locale

        let startDate = formatter.date(from: "2018 08 10")!
        let endDate = formatter.date(from: "2018 10 10")!

        let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate, endDate: endDate)
        return parameters

    }

    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, willDisplay cell: JTAppleCell, forItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let dateCell = cell as! DateCell
            dateCell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text
    }


    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, cellForItemAt date: Date, cellState: CellState, indexPath: IndexPath) -> JTAppleCell {

        if let cell = calendarView.dequeueReusableJTAppleCell(withReuseIdentifier: "dateCell", for: indexPath) as? DateCell {
            cell.dateLabel.text = cellState.text
            cell.configure(date: cellState.text)
            return cell
        }
        return DateCell()
    }


    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didSelectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell, cellState: CellState) {
        guard let validCell = cell as? DateCell else { return }
        validCell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    }


    func calendar(_ calendar: JTAppleCalendarView, didDeselectDate date: Date, cell: JTAppleCell, cellState: CellState) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Will be much easier to help if you can show me your code regarding how you setup JTAppleCalendar delegate and datasource.

Comment: I have updated the post with the code. Please check it and kindly let me know the solution.

Answer (score 0):

[image]You actually forgot to call `delegate` and `dataSource`. Please adjust your viewDidLoad() as follow:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   calendarView.calendarDataSource = self
   calendarView.calendarDelegate = self

}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not able to call them. That is the problem. It is saying "Cannot assign value of type CalendarViewController to type UICollectionViewDelegate."

Comment: Can you upload screenshot of calendarView outlets?

Comment: I uploaded. Please check my post.

Comment: still don't have a clue... would you please upload the screenshot like i just did, before we go into a despair end? ahahaha

Comment: It is the same as yours. If possible, could you please give me a sample project on the Calendar. If you have a github account, please share with me your username.

Comment: Apologize for late response. Unfortunately I'm not yet update my github (bad habit indeed). I wonder, didn't the unofficial JTAppleCalendar has a good tutorial to how to build a calendar from scratch?

Comment: Please feel free to contact me when you stuck with the tutorial.

Comment: thats what i was thinking. The video tutorials were pretty clear 